# Resorting nested list A according to nested list B

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

How can sort nested list according to each other? e.g. I have the following list:

```
list1 = {{A 1,B 2,C 2,D 2,E 3,F 1,G 2},{A 2,B 1,C 3,D 3,H 3},{A 2,B 2,C 1,E 3,F 2,A 1,D 2},..}
```

and I want sort each sublist in list 1 according to their reference position (list 2):

```
list2 = {{A 1,B 2,C 2,D 2,E 3,F 3,G 3},{A 2,B 1,D 3,H 3,C 3},{A 2,A 1,B 2,C 1,F 2,E 3,D 2},...}}
```

I want this output:

```
list1 = {{A 1,B 2,C 2,D 2,E 3,F 3,G 3},{A 2,B 1,D 3,H 3,C 3},{A 2,A 1,B 2,C 1,F 2,E 3,D 2},...}}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example of what you want - i.e. valid input, and the expected output

Comment: By the way don't use capitals like C, D, E, I. They have built-in meanings and may not sort properly.

Comment: I cannot see any difference between `list2` and your desired output.